# appending itertools.combinations to a list gives empty lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make pairs from the given list of items. I am using *combinations* from *itertools* in python

```
def call_jaccard(listOfItems):
    returnList = []
    if (len(listOfItems) >= 2):
        returnList.append(list(combinations(listOfItems, 2)))
    return returnList
```

The output I am getting is however :

```
[[(u'U3', u'U8')]], [], [], [], [], [[(u'U9', u'U10'), (u'U9', u'U2'), (u'U10', u'U2')]], [], [], [], [], [], [[(u'U3', u'U8')]], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [[(u'U9', u'U10'), (u'U9', u'U2'), (u'U10', u'U2')]], [], [], [], [[(u'U9', u'U2')]], [], [], [], [[(u'U3', u'U8')]], [[(u'U3', u'U8')]], [], [], [], [], [], [[(u'U3', u'U8')]], [], [], [], [[(u'U9', u'U2')]], [[(u'U9', u'U10'), (u'U9', u'U2'), (u'U10', u'U2')]], []]
```

How can I get rid of these extra [ ]?

I also tried checking if the items I am appending are not empty as follows:

```
def call_jaccard(listOfItems):
        returnList = []
        if (len(listOfItems) >= 2):
            for x in (list(combinations(listOfItems, 2))):
                            if len(x) >0:
        returnList.append(x)
```

but still getting the same empty [ ]. Please help!

listOfItems will contain a list:

```
[1,2,3] or [1] or [1,2]
```

Expected Output is combinations of the above. In case of single item it should ignore.

Comment: In the case `len(pair) < 2`, you'll be returning an empty list.

Comment: What is `pair`? You never use `listOfItems`. Can you show what is in `pair` and what your expected output is.

Comment: Sorry. It was basically listOfItems. Made the edits

Comment: @MosesKoledoye How can I avoid that? Please help

Comment: Can you confirm the expected output? For [1,2,3] you want [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]?

Comment: @AmanMathur You could return the original list when `len(pair) < 2` or skip the function call in case you're doing this in a loop and you don't want any output for lists with length < 2

Comment: @MattR.Wilson Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye This function is being called on a Spark RDD. The RDD in turn contains some lists with length < 1.

Comment: Your first function returns `[[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]]` for the input of `[1,2,3]`. I understand that isn't exactly what you want, however, I'm unable to reproduce the empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is

```
def call_jaccard(listOfItems):
    if len(listOfItems) < 2:
        return []
    return [list(i) for i in combinations(listOfItems, 2)]
```

`itertools.combinations` iterates tuples of the pairs you want. To cast each pair and the outer collection to lists you need to cast them explicitly.

```
call_jaccard([1,2,3])
>>> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: I am calling the function on multiple size lists.. like [1,2,3], [1], [1,2]. So when this function is called on the above input of lists, it gives [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]], [ ], [1,2]]

Comment: I think you need to clarify your input and expected output. Are you wanting to call the function once with `[[1,2,3], [1], [1,2]]` or three times, once for each inner list? And what do you want your final output to be?

Comment: a map(call_jaccard) is being called on an Spark RDD which consists of  [1,2,3], [1], [1,2].

Comment: You want: `map(call_jaccard, ([1,2,3], [1], [1,2])) == [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2]]`? That can't be done. The `map` function outputs exactly one item for each item in the given iterable. You need a second step to filter and flatten the result.